# Forest: increasing horizontal separation by level bottom-up

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, trees

I used `qtree` for a while and although there's not much that it can do that `forest` can't, there is one effect that `qtree` has by default that I quite like, which is that it automatically increases the distance between nodes in a tree from the bottom up in a way that I haven't been able to get `forest` to do. This makes it so that (broadly) higher nodes in a tree are spaced out a bit and lower nodes are closer together.

Here's a MWE demonstrating what I'm talking about; first, there's a `qtree` tree and then a clumsy approximation I tried to make in `forest`, by playing with the read-only option `level`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}

\Tree [.x x [.x x [.x x [.x x [.x x x ]]]]]

\begin{center}
\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    l sep=0.8ex,
    l sep+=(1/((level)+1))*1.28^1.5ex, % inter-node distance is relative to level
    l-=3ex, % constrains spacing of nodes
    inner sep=0,
    calign=fixed edge angles, 
    calign angle=63,
},
%
%        
[x[x][x[x][x[x][x[x][x[x][x]]]]]]
%
%
\end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My question is as follows: is there a proper way to achieve this effect in `forest`?

My rough impression is that `qtree` has a system whereby it automatically adds a bit more horizontal separation every level from the bottom up, i.e. it calculates the absolute distance of any given set of siblings from their lowest descendant in a tree somehow.

Having read the documentation, it seems that `forest` tracks absolute levels of nodes with the read-only option `level` , but this is calculated top-down. It may be instructive for me to understand if there is a way to calculate a nodes level relative to its most distant direct descendant in `forest`, but so far, I've not been able to figure this out. Or maybe there's some other reason why this wouldn't work to begin with.

Comment: You should be able to calculate a node's level relative to its most distant direct descendant fairly easily. I'm not sure what you mean by 'absolute' levels. They're all relative in some sense, but they're also not necessarily fixed until the end. But I don't know if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `l` is a measure of the distance between levels. If you want to affect the horizontal separation between nodes on a level, you need to be looking at `s sep`/`s` etc. But perhaps you know this and your existing setup is aimed at customising vertical distancing.

Comment: It's been a while since I studied qtree, but If I remember correctly, the increased separation of the upper levels is due to how qtree "packs" the tree. In forest, you should get the same effect by setting `fit=rectangle` (for the entire tree).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to calculate how distant a node's most distant descendant is in terms of levels. In a non-fancy tree, we can do this early in the processing. If your tree changes its structure, you'd obviously need to do the calculation after the structure is finalised.

We start by defining a couple of `count` options for `forest`.

```
\forestset{%
  declare count={level of most distant descendant}{0},
  declare count={steps to most distant descendant}{0},
}
```

We can then use these keys in the tree's preamble together with one of `forest`s `aggregate` functions, `.max` and a little `forestmath` to calculate the number we want.

```
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n children=0{}{% we don't calculate anything for terminal nodes which have no descendants by definition
      level of most distant descendant/.max={ > O {level} }{descendants},% get the maximum level of the node's descendants
      steps to most distant descendant/.process={ OOw2 {level of most distant descendant}{level}{#1-#2} },% subtract the node's own level to get the most distant descendant's distance in terms of number of levels
```

This example adds the number as a label for illustrative purposes, but you presumably want to use it to adjust the formatting of your tree.

```
      label/.process={ Ow1 {steps to most distant descendant}{{[red, font=\tiny]east:#1}}},
    }
  }
```

[image: labelled nodes]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  declare count={level of most distant descendant}{0},
  declare count={steps to most distant descendant}{0},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
  for tree={
    l sep'=0.8ex,
    l sep+=(1/((level)+1))*1.28^1.5ex, % inter-node distance is relative to level
    l'-=3ex, % constrains spacing of nodes
    inner sep=0pt,
    calign=fixed edge angles, 
    calign angle=63,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n children=0{}{%
      level of most distant descendant/.max={ > O {level} }{descendants},
      steps to most distant descendant/.process={ OOw2 {level of most distant descendant}{level}{#1-#2} },
      label/.process={ Ow1 {steps to most distant descendant}{{[red, font=\tiny]east:#1}}},
    }
  }
  [x[x][x[x][x[x][x[x][x[x][x]]]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Of course, if your trees were all this simply structured, you could get the number you wanted with less hassle because all nodes with descendants share a common pair of most distant descendants. Since that's not true of trees in general, however, we have to find the most distant descendant(s) for each node with descendants.